# php mail function not working in my server

Tags: php, email

I am using PHP `mail` function to send a mail, But am testing my local sever mail has been sent but my live i cant sent mail. Can you please help me?

```
$email_message = "<b>Form details below</b> <br/><br/>";
$email_message .= "Name: ".$_POST['name']."<br/>";
$email_message .= "Email: ".$_POST['email']."<br/>";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."<br/>";
$email_message .= "Message: ".$_POST['message']."<br/>";

$CusHeaders  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$CusHeaders .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$CusHeaders .= 'From: <'.$_POST['email'].'>' . "\r\n";

$to = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
$subject = "Admin - Our Site! Comment from " ;

if(mail($to,$subject,$email_message,$CusHeaders)) {
 echo "Email Has Been Sent .";
} else {
 echo "Cannot Send Email ";
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Spam box; try that :p

Comment: am not receive no mail in inbox and spam

Comment: What is the output "email sent " or "not sent" ?

Comment: share us your configs

Comment: am getting `Cannot Send Email` only

Comment: @Abdulla configs means... which configs?

Comment: Try this 
$CusHeaders .= 'From: '.$_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
or
$CusHeaders .= 'From: SOME_NAME <'.$_POST['email'].'>' . "\r\n";

Comment: Are you testing it on local host or a live server??

Comment: @ManojSalvi am testing my local sever mail has been sent but my live i cant sent mail

Answer (score 1):

Why use `mail()` when you have codeigniter `email` class.

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Use [`mandrillapp`](https://mandrillapp.com/login/?referrer=%2F) for sending mail using SMTP, and add credentials for `email` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as html(test)

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"/>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone" />
<input type="text" name="message" placeholder="message"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
   if(isset($_POST[submit]))
   {
    $email_message = "<b>Form details below</b> <br/><br/>";
    $email_message .= "Name: ".$_POST['name']."<br/>";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".$_POST['email']."<br/>";
    $email_message .= "Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."<br/>";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".$_POST['message']."<br/>";

  $CusHeaders  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $CusHeaders .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
  $CusHeaders .= 'From: <'.$_POST['email'].'>' . "\r\n";

$to = "p******@gmail.com";
$subject = "Admin - Our Site! Comment from " ;

if(mail($to,$subject,$email_message,$CusHeaders)) {
echo "Email Has Been Sent .";
}
else {
echo "Cannot Send Email ";
}
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: check my answer its working, I have checked on server also.

Comment: its not working for me. i think my server issue, but i cant fix this issue. any way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try it. It's Working

```
$email_message = "<b>Form details below</b> <br/><br/>";
    $email_message .= "Name: ".$_POST['name']."<br/>";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".$_POST['email']."<br/>";
    $email_message .= "Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."<br/>";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".$_POST['message']."<br/>";

    $CusHeaders  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $CusHeaders .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $CusHeaders .= 'From: '.$_POST['email'].'' . "\r\n";
     $CusHeaders .= 'Reply-To: '.$_POST['email'].'' . "\r\n";
     $CusHeaders .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


    $to = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Admin - Our Site! Comment from " ;

    if(mail($to,$subject,$email_message,$CusHeaders)) {
     echo "Email Has Been Sent .";
    } else {
     echo "Cannot Send Email ";
    }
```

Comment: Its not working in my server

Comment: am testing my local sever mail has been sent but my live i cant sent mail

Comment: @MansoorH it's working on live server you can check here http://www.w3ctrl.in/mail-test.php

Comment: but my live server not working http://apple-live-support.com/index-5.html

Comment: i think my server issue, but i cant fix this issue.

Comment: @MansoorH please select my answer. for your server you can check normal mail function in any test php file. if it is not working contact to your hosting provider.

Comment: ok sure. i will contact my hosting provider any way thanks

Comment: @MansoorH  for any other issue on same problem u can comment here

Comment: Ok sure. i will let you know